# Volume of Revolution question

Tags: calculus

[image]

I've been stuck for  while now.
I rewrote the equations in terms of x. $e(2-y)=x,\ e^y=x$

The integral I used was:

$\displaystyle \pi\int_0^2(2e-ey)^2-(e^y)^2dy$

But I don't think that's right, the answer is: $\dfrac{5e^2-e}{6}\pi$

Do I need separate integrals for each curve, and different bounds for them too or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to split it into two parts:
$$
\displaystyle \pi\int_0^1e^{2y}dy+ \pi\int_1^2 e^2(2-y)^2dy
$$
If you notice that the second integral represents the volume of a cone it might save you some work.

Comment: Thank you, I've evaluated the integral and got the answer. I notice that the second integral represented the volume of a cone after you pointed it out - but please could you elaborate on how it could have saved me some work? I'm assuming you meant there was a shorter way of doing it.

Comment: Sure. The volume of the cone is 1/3 times the base area $(\pi e^2)$ times the height $(1)$.